# Error on realloc : corrupted size vs. prev_size

Tags: c, malloc, realloc, sigabrt

I'm coding in C.
The goal of my algorithm is to double each char c we find in an array str.
I have to run a few tests, for the first test I call `doubleChar("~/fichier.txt", '~')` and it works fine, but my second test is `doubleChar("une commande # commentaire", '#')` and I get the error from the title.
When i tried to debug it, the error was on the realloc line.

In debugger I get this error:

> Program Received signal SIGABRT Stack trace is available in the 'Call Stack' tab

Any idea why?

Here's my code:

```
    char * doubleChar(const char *str, char c){
assert(str!=NULL);
    char *newString=malloc(sizeof(str) * sizeof(char));
    int a = 0;
    while(str[a] != '\0'){
        newString[a]=str[a];
        a++;
    }
    newString[a]='\0';
    int i = 0;
    while(newString[i] != '\0'){
        if(newString[i] == c){
            newString = (char *)realloc(newString, stringLength(newString)*sizeof(char) + sizeof(char));
            for(int j=stringLength(newString)+1; j>i; j--){
                newString[j]=newString[j-1];
            }
            i++; //we add 1 to i so we don't find the char we just added
        }
        i++;
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: That's potentially a lot of reallocating. Consider `doubleChar("!!!AhHa!!!", '!')` A quicker approach is to loop over the string once counting the number of matching characters, then allocate the space to hold the original string + count of matches + 1 (for the terminating nul). Copy the characters in a second loop, adding the duplicate characters as you go. One malloc and no reallocs.

Comment: That's a really good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *newString=malloc(sizeof(str) * sizeof(char));
```

Since `str` is a `const char *`, the `sizeof(str)` is how many bytes a `const char *` takes on your platform. That's not what you want. What you want to pass to `malloc` is the length of the string you want to store, making sure to leave an extra byte for the terminating zero. In this case, that's `(strlen(str) + 1)`.

```
newString = (char *)realloc(newString, stringLength(newString)*sizeof(char) + sizeof(char));
```

This is probably also wrong. You need `(strlen(newString) + 2)` to leave one byte for the newly-added character and one byte for the zero terminator. It's hard to be sure though because I can't tell what your `stringLength` function does.

Also, `sizeof(char)` is, by definition, one. The `sizeof` function returns the size in characters.

It's much easier to understand `strlen(newString) + 2` than `stringLength(newString)*sizeof(char) + sizeof(char)` because `strlen` is a standard function and `sizeof(char)` is verbose and ugly. So I'd strongly suggest changing this to `strlen(newString) + 2`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was clear and it did fix my issue.
I was putting sizeof(char) because i wasn't sure if it was always 1 between platforms.

Comment: @colin The size of char itself can be bigger than 8 bits, but it always returns sizeof char == 1. If you need to know about the bits in a char there's a C required macro CHAR_BIT which tells you.